# match/case statement raises SyntaxError in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.9

I'd like to use the `match/case` statement but currently PyCharm does not like it and when I try to run this code:

```py
def test(action):
    match action:
        case "send":
            pass
        case "create":
            pass
        case "dump":
            pass
```

it tells me

```
    match action:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I use python 3.9.1 and PyCharm 2021.2.3 Pro. The keywords `match` and `case` are blue so I guess PyCharm recognizes them but is not able to run it. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Python version less than 3.10.

[PEP 634: Structural Pattern Matching](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching) is **introduced in python 3.10**. See [What’s New In Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html)
for more information.